# Crash on Android 4.2.2: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to finish input event. status=-11

Tags: android

I got a crash on Android 4.2.2.

Exception stack trace:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to finish input event. status=-11
     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeFinishInputEvent(Native Method)
     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.finishInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:152)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.finishInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5002)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3654)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4966)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4926)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5085)
     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:190)
     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:128)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:151)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5468)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:936)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug, see here in the google issue tracker :

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=108859